# Writing a bash script on a new box, Escaping Code

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

There may be a question out there for this somewhere. But I wasn't able to find it easily.

Basically I want to write a bash script on a new box. A script that I've previously used.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash -ex
hi='hello world!'
echo $hi
```

I've always used (for multiline output)

```
cat > script.sh <<EOF
#!/bin/bash -ex
hi='hello world!'
echo $hi
EOF
```

But as you may have noticed this has issues with $hi, and other symbols. Is there a good way to do this? Tips Tricks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should quote the End-Of-File marker, otrherwise the variable expansion (or rather, everything starting with a `$`, will get the current context.

Compare:

```
hi=here
cat >file.sh <<EOF
#!/bin/sh
hi=there
echo $hi
EOF
sh file.sh
```

(outputs `here`)

```
hi=here
cat >file.sh <<\EOF
#!/bin/sh
hi=there
echo $hi
EOF
sh file.sh
```

outputs `there`

```
hi=here
cat >file.sh <<'EOF'
#!/bin/sh
hi=there
echo $hi
EOF
sh file.sh
```

outputs `there`.

Alternatively, you can quote the `$`:

```
hi=here
cat >file.sh <<EOF
#!/bin/sh
hi=there
echo \$hi
EOF
sh file.sh
```

(outputs `there`)

This initially surprising behavior comes in very handy when there is a need to generate slightly different scripts for various purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have figured it out. Still interested in how others solve this problem:

```
cat > script.sh <<'EOF'
#!/bin/bash -ex
hi='hello world!'
echo $hi
EOF
```

As a note, it seems like freebsd requires:

```
cat > script.sh <<'EOF'
#!/bin/bash -ex
hi='hello world!'
echo $hi
'EOF'
```

Comment: What shell are you using on FreeBSD?

Comment: markdown isn't being my friend. But -bash, through sudo su

Comment: Check with `bash --version`.

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (amd64-portbld-freebsd10.1)